# Linux with HDD Vs VMware with SSD - disk corruption on power failure?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, vmware

I manage around 120+ servers in DC. We have installed linux using HDD (SAS drive) and VMWare on SSD. We had power issues with our data center two times, We never had the problem with server having SSD+Vmware, But we have booting problem with linux server(ext4) using SAS drive.

My question is, the SAS drive is causing the probelm or Linux ? (Whereas we dont have problem with VMware + SSD servers)

Edit: This is observed multiple times, not just once.

Answer (score 1):

Everything with mechanical moving parts will wear down over time, and the start-up is the time when the HDD motor will have the greatest load.

In server use, you have HDDs that may have been warm & spinning continuously for years. When such a HDD stops and cools down, there is an elevated risk for latent hardware failures to become actual failures: perhaps the worn bearings now have just a little too much friction while cold to satisfy the HDD firmware's spin-up-time self-test, or perhaps some electrolytic capacitors on the HDD's circuit board have degraded with time and no longer can keep the voltages quite stable enough when full power is needed.

This is a well-known thing with HDDs in general, and it can apply to other components too: perhaps a fan's bearing has worn out so far that it is only staying in alignment by gyroscopic forces, and when it stops and cools down, it goes out of alignment and becomes stuck. And so a server that was running "perfectly fine" before the shutdown may have one or more fan failures when restarted.

An old HP-UX service engineer once told me that when an old server that has been running continuously for a long time needs downtime for maintenance, it will be smart to first fully shut it down and restart it once without doing anything else: a restart will give any components that are on the edge of failure a chance to reveal themselves.

Also a customer won't be able to convincingly say "you broke my server" if all that was done so far was a controlled shutdown and a restart attempt, which just happened to reveal previously-unknown failures.

If you are talking about filesystem-level issues, SSDs do tend to need less power than HDDs, so all else being equal, a system with SSDs might have a slightly better chance of getting any on-going write operations completed when the power is lost, before the capacitors in the PSUs (and in the disks themselves) actually run out of power.

Nevertheless, power failures in a datacenter are a very bad thing. If the only problems you get after that is a few servers out of 120+ failing to boot, you should consider yourself lucky: you got off easy.

If your datacenter does not have have enough UPS capacity (to either handle the power failure or transition to a local generator, whichever is appropriate), then you still should have enough for controlled shutdown of all systems with some reserve, *and* a tested automated process that triggers a rapid controlled shutdown when the UPS's detect a loss of incoming power for longer than X seconds. If you don't have enough UPS capacity for even that, someone is not being serious with this datacenter business.